# Dropzone add id on init function and sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dropzone.js

I need to get id of my existing images into dropzone preview and ability of sending sort order to backend

#### What I have

1. get existing images
2. sort images

#### What I need

1. Add images IDs to preview
2. send sort order to back-end

#### Code

> Each part of the code is commented for better understanding

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
  var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
    headers: {
      "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
    },
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
    dictDefaultMessage: "Drag an image here to upload, or click to select one",
    maxFiles: 15, // Maximum Number of Files
    maxFilesize: 8, // MB
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    url: '{{ url('admin/dropzoneStore') }}/'+encodeURI('{{$product->id}}'),
    dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',
    dictFileTooBig: 'Image is bigger than 8MB',

    // get uploaded images in dropzone box
    init: function() {
      myDropzone = this;
      // get current images
      const images = @json($images);
      $.each(images, function(index, value) {
        var mockFile = {name: value.name, size: value.size, id: value.id };
        myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
        myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, "/images/"+value.name);
        myDropzone.options.complete.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
        myDropzone.options.success.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
      });
    }
  });
  // remove files from both view and database
  myDropzone.on("removedfile", function(file,response) {
      $.ajax({
          url: '{{ url('admin/destroyOnEdit') }}/'+encodeURI(file.name),
          type: 'DELETE',
          dataType: "JSON",
          data: {
              "name": file.name,
              "_method": 'DELETE',
              "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
          },
          success:function(data) {
            myDropzone.removeFile(file);
          }
      });
  });
  // sort images in preview (need to send this sort to back-end and update images "sort" column value)
  $(function() {
    $(".dropzone").sortable({
      items: '.dz-preview',
      cursor: 'move',
      opacity: 0.5,
      containment: '.dropzone',
      distance: 20,
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      stop: function(event, ui) {
        var cloned = $('div#botofform').clone()
        $('#botofform').html("")
        $('.dropzone .dz-complete').each(function() {
          var data_id = $(this).data('id')
          console.log('event', event)
          console.log('ui', ui)
          console.log('data_id', data_id)
          $(cloned).find("input[data-id=" + data_id + "]").clone().appendTo($('#botofform'))
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

**Any idea?**

Comment: Hi, can you show `images` output ?

Comment: @Swati hi here you go https://ibb.co/bRQZ0Gh

Comment: no `images` output i.e : json structure :D

Comment: oh :D wait......

Comment: here you go https://ibb.co/5M9HCgz

Comment: The `id` i.e : `103` is unique for all images ?

Comment: yes it's unique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your `id` is unique you can use this id to identify each images in your dropzone .So, inside `init` function whenever you append new images you can add `data-id` to each preview div using `attr('data-id', value.id)` and append input-box inside your bottom div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#my-awesome-dropzone", {
  headers: {
    "X-CSRF-TOKEN": $("meta[name='csrf-token']").attr("content")
  },
  acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
  dictDefaultMessage: "Drag an image here to upload, or click to select one",
  maxFiles: 15, // Maximum Number of Files
  maxFilesize: 8, // MB
  addRemoveLinks: true,
  //url: '{{ url('admin/dropzoneStore') }}/'+encodeURI('{{$product->id}}'),
  dictRemoveFile: 'Remove',
  dictFileTooBig: 'Image is bigger than 8MB',

  // get uploaded images in dropzone box
  init: function() {
    myDropzone = this;
    // get current images
    // const images = @json($images);

    var images = [{
      id: 103,
      img_alt: "svsss",
      name: "IMG_20201007_110637.jpg",
      sort: 0
    }, {
      id: 104,
      img_alt: "svsss1",
      name: "IMG_20201019_131338.jpg",
      sort: 1
    }, {
      id: 105,
      img_alt: "svsss3",
      name: "IMG_2020101_131339.jpg",
      sort: 2
    }, {
      id: 106,
      img_alt: "svsss4",
      name: "IMG_2020101_131340.jpg",
      sort: 3
    }]
    $.each(images, function(index, value) {
      var mockFile = {
        name: value.name,
        size: value.size,
        id: value.id
      };

      myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
      myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, "/images/" + value.name);
      myDropzone.options.complete.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
      myDropzone.options.success.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
      $(mockFile.previewElement).attr('data-id', value.id); //add data-id to preview div
      $('#botofform').append('<input type="text" class="cimages" name="cimages[]" data-id = "' + value.id + '" value="' + value.name + '" sort="' + value.sort + '">'); //append image value(name) and data-id(id) and sort(value as well)

    });
  }
});

$(function() {
  $(".dropzone").sortable({
    items: '.dz-preview',
    cursor: 'move',
    opacity: 0.5,
    containment: '.dropzone',
    distance: 20,
    tolerance: 'pointer',
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var cloned = $('div#botofform').clone()
      $('#botofform').html("")
      console.clear()
      $('.dropzone .dz-complete').each(function(i) {
        var data_id = $(this).data('id')
        console.log('data_id-- ' + data_id + " || sort --" + i)
        //find input change attr and then clone same...
        $(cloned).find("input[data-id=" + data_id + "]").attr("sort", i).clone().appendTo($('#botofform'))
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone" action="#">
  <div class="fallback">
    <input name="cimages[]" type="file" multiple />
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div id="botofform"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much this adds the id, but what about `$(".dropzone").sortable({`? how can I send image order(position) to backend? let say i moved my image to second place and in `$(".dropzone").sortable({` function send images id plus position of the image (i.e. 2) so I can update that image sort column.

Comment: You need to have `0,1..` order ? or with `id` you can do ?

Comment: i need both, id in order to know which image i should update and the position number in order to know what value i should put. so it's more like: `id: 130, order: 2` something like that

Comment: I see wait i will update with that as well :)