# Dropzone Display existing files

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, dropzone.js, dropzone

I am using Dropzone js to upload images to my application. This works fine on the insert page but I need to be able to edit records and add or change already existing images associated with the record. The overall application is using Laravel.

I am trying to implement this using the following code but I am no JS expert and can't seem to get it working for example in my setup displayExistingFile is not recognised as a function. How would I do this based on my existing code?

I am trying to pass in the existing files in the init function with  var image_data;

```
   var uploadedDocumentMap = {};
            var uploadedOrder = 0;
            $('#advert_images_zone').dropzone({
                url: '{{ route('adverts.storeMedia') }}',
                method: 'post',
                maxFilesize: 12, // MB
                maxFiles: 6,
                dictDefaultMessage: 'Drop images anywhere to upload (6 images Max)',
                acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
                thumbnailWidth: 100,
                thumbnailHeight: 100,
                addRemoveLinks: true,
                previewsContainer: ".dropzone-previews",
                previewTemplate: '<li><figure><img data-dz-thumbnail /><i title="Remove Image" class="icon-trash" data-dz-remove ></i></figure></li>',
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                },
                success: function (file, response) {
                    $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="advert_images[]" value="' + response.name + '">');
                    uploadedOrder++;
                    uploadedDocumentMap[file.name] = {name:response.name, order:uploadedOrder}
                   // console.log(uploadedDocumentMap);
                    $('#image_order').val(JSON.stringify(uploadedDocumentMap));
                },
                removedfile: function (file) {
                    var name = ''
                    if (typeof file.file_name !== 'undefined') {
                        name = file.file_name
                    } else {
                        name = uploadedDocumentMap[file.name].name
                    }

                    var url = '{{ route('adverts.removeMedia') }}';

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url : url,
                        data: {name : name,"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",}
                    }).done(function (data) {
                        file.previewElement.remove();
                        delete uploadedDocumentMap[file.name];
                        $('#image_order').val(JSON.stringify(uploadedDocumentMap));
                        $('form').find('input[name="advert_images[]"][value="' + name + '"]').remove();
                    }).fail(function () {
                        console.log('Image could not be removed');
                    });
                },
                init: function() {
                    var myDropzone = this;
                    this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                        file.previewElement.remove();
                    });

                    var image_data = JSON.parse($('#image_json').val());

                    $.each(image_data, function(key, value)
                    {
                        var mockFile = {
                            name: value.name,
                            size: value.size
                        };

                        var path = "{{asset ('storage/ad_images/')}}";
                        console.log(mockFile);
                        myDropzone.options.addedfile.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
                        myDropzone.options.thumbnail.call(myDropzone, mockFile, path + "/thumbnails/" + value.name);
                        myDropzone.options.complete.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
                        myDropzone.options.success.call(myDropzone, mockFile);
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi what does `image_data` has ?

Comment: A json object, mokeFile will have this: {name: "600214b1e19c1_93300940-clownfish-amphiprioninae-in-aquarium-tank-with-reef-as-background.jpg", size: 78312}

Comment: You can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65419225/10606400)  will be helpful .

Comment: That has definitely got me further, I have updated the code accordingly. Still has some issues though. The final myDropzone.options.success.call(myDropzone, mockFile); call cases a: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined error and is there no way to get dropzone to auto generate the thubnails from the existing files or resize them?

Comment: Hi its calling your `success: function (file, response) {` function  and giving you undefined  in this line `response.name` remove this line `myDropzone.options.success.call(myDropzone, mockFile);` completely see if that works .

Comment: Yes I understand that. I then need to create another function so that the remove file still works.