# How to get a URL from server and convert it into a valid Dropzone.js file object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I've just been trying to figure out how to get a file URL from the server and display it as an image in dropzone.
The problem I have is I have no idea how to convert that URL into a dropzone file object.
I've checked out [this](https://gitlab.com/meno/dropzone/-/wikis/faq#how-to-show-files-already-stored-on-server), and I get the idea, but the explanation isn't that clear.

Here is my code:

```js
$('.c-section').on('click', '.s-body-row', async function () {  
  // AJAX stuff
  let file = res.data.file
  // File syntax is { name: smthng, url: smthng }
  upDropzone.emit("addedfile", { name: file.name }) // error is here
  upDropzone.emit("thumbnail", { name: file.name }, file.url) // This does not run (obviously)
})
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please Help, somebody... I still can't figure out the solution

Comment: Can you add a runnable snippet

Comment: @codeRdevelopR , are you trying to get an url of already uploaded file and display it as an image ?

Comment: Hi, try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65419225/10606400) answer.

Comment: If there's an error, what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following :

```
var mockFile = { 
                name: 'name.jpg', 
                size: 12345, 
                type: 'image/jpeg', 
                status: Dropzone.ADDED, 
                url: 'url.com',
                accepted: true
            };

            // Call the default addedfile event handler
            myDropzone.emit('addedfile', mockFile);
            //show the thumbnail of the file:
            myDropzone.emit('thumbnail', mockFile, 'url.com');
            myDropzone.emit('complete', mockFile);
            myDropzone.files.push(mockFile);
```

Comment: Yeah I had to refactor a lot of things to get it working.. Thx anyway